# Using args in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following in my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
 geth-testnet:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:  
        GETH_REPO: 'https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum'
        GETH_VERSION: 'v1.8.12'
        RPC_LISTEN_PORT: 8546
    command: "--rpcport ${RPC_LISTEN_PORT}"
    entrypoint: 
        - "geth"
    tty: true
    image: geth-node-testnet:v1.8.12
    container_name: geth-node-testnet
    ports:
      - '8546:8546'
    volumes:
      - /root/.ethereum
```

When I run, `docker-compose up --build`, expect it to run the following command:

```
geth -rpcport 8546
```

However, I get the following error

```
flag needs an argument: -rpcport
```

So, the value for `RPC_LISTEN_PORT` is not correctly substituted.

I have `ARG RPC_LISTEN_PORT` in my dockerfile

Comment: Try changing the value for `command` to an array of strings instead of a whitespace-delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

Double checked your question, seems `command: "--rpcport ${RPC_LISTEN_PORT}"` cannot utilize the value you put in `docker-compose.yml`.

So afford two solutions:

1. `export RPC_LISTEN_PORT=8546` in bash before you do `compose` command.
2. New a `.env` file in the same folder, put `RPC_LISTEN_PORT=8546` to it.

Comment: Actually, I tried add this in docker-compose
`
environment:   
        RPC_LISTEN_PORT: 8546
`
I got the same error
I also tried this in my Dockerfile
`
ENV RPC_LISTEN_PORT="${RPC_LISTEN_PORT}"
`
I again got the same error.